# installing new wheel bearings motorbike

Tags: motorcycle, wheel-bearing

I replaced the wheel beaings on my rear wheel and the bike runs fine. 
 When I installed the new bearings I couldn't turn the inner race by hand (almost like it was touching the spacer). 
 It turns and spins fine on the bike, is there anything to worry about?
 Cheers

Comment: Could you spin them by hand before they were installed?

Comment: Yeah, and it spins fine all installed on the bike too.